# Building dynamic_rnn from scratch in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, dynamic, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am coding rnn similar to dynamic_rnn provided by tensorflow. I tried to see the code on GitHub but cannot understand how they have implemented it. I want to build it from scratch so that I can customize rnn from within. How to do that?

Currently, my approach is thinking of a truncated time series as a tensor use tf.scan() and find the new hidden state for all time series. Then use tf.map_fn to find the output for the new stacked hidden variables. Finally, use tf.while_loop() to find the error for each tensor on the first dimension of stacked output and do back propagation with that loss.

My concern will the graph be dynamic after doing this. I mean let say first I unrolled for 5 times and then 4 times will the graph erase that one node rolled before?

Will this work?

Please guide.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RNNs should be implementable with just one loop (`scan`/`map_fn`/etc. are all based on `while_loop` with one or more `TensorArray`s) which passes state and computes a loss all in one. One advantage of these constructs is that your graph is a fixed sized but the number of iterations can vary (or be very large without increasing graph size).

However, iterating over variable-length sequences is usually not great for maximizing performance. Generally taking good advantage of SIMD instructions on the CPU or parallelism on the GPU requires at least some batching, in which case it's a good idea to chop up your sequences and batch these segments together. There are tools such as [SequenceQueueingStateSaver](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/sequence_queueing_state_saver.py#L617) which let you produce fixed-size batches from many variable-length sequences.